# Getting data from text file (separated by spaces) using variable lengths into R

Tags: r

I have a text file similar to this (separated by spaces):

```
x <- "DF12 This is an example 1 This
DF12 This is an 1232 This is
DF14 This is 12334 This is an
DF15 This 23 This is an example
"
```

and I know the field lengths of each variable (there is 5 variables in this data set), which are:

```
varlength <- c(2, 2, 18, 5, 18)
```

How can I import this kind of data into R, using the varlength variable as an field separator indicator?

Comment: Cross posting is rude because people in one community don't see the answers from the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per Barry Rowlingson on r-help (where you seem to have cross-posted):

> ?read.fwf
>
> Read Fixed Width Format Files
>
> Description:
>
> ```
>  Read a table of *f*ixed *w*idth *f*ormatted data into a
>  'data.frame'.
> ```
>
> Usage:
>
> ```
>  read.fwf(file, widths, header = FALSE, sep = "\t",
>           skip = 0, row.names, col.names, n = -1,
>           buffersize = 2000, ...)
> ```